# How can I using this variable?

Tags: java

I want to using this variable (ntime[]) in main class
I think I must using 'extends', but I don't know how I using that.
What Can I using variable, and How can I use it?
I want to know It is using extends, or another variable it can.
Thank you

I was using extends
~~ void main(String args[]) extends *** throws IOException
&
~~ void main extends *** (String args[]) *** throws IOException

but it is not work

import java.util.Calendar;

```
class *****
 {
 public void ***** throws IOException
 {
 int [] ntime = new int [6];
 BufferedReader inbr = new BufferedReader (new
 InputStreamReader(System.in));
 Calendar now= Calendar.getInstance();
 ntime[0] = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 ntime[1] = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
....
 ntime[5] = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
 }
 }


 class *****  {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
 {

***** objecta = new ***();
   objecta.test01();
  System.out.println("Time is  " + ntime[0] + ... + ntime[5]);
 }
 }
```

symbol:   variable ntime
  location: class ***

Comment: Please post real, compilable, code here. See [mcve]. I'm not sure what you mean  with the `***` and the `~~~` but that doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `main` does not have access to the int array.

You can solve this by returning the int[] from your function

```
class Thing {
    public int[] fun() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        return new int[]{
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        };
    }
}
```

then in `main`, you can have

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        int[] ntime = thing.fun();

        System.out.println("time is " + ntime[0]);
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since ntime is a member of the *** class.

To be able access it, you have to create first an instance of that class and make sure that ntime isn't a private member. Which i think you did when you created your 'objecta'. And then you will have to access your variable ntime through that object.

For example you would call

```
objecta.ntime[0]
```